# Null Pointer Exception when trying to detect end of ListView in Android app

Tags: java, android, listview

So, right now I have an activity that populates a ListView with dummy entries. I then set an OnScrollListener to the list. This works fine.

Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    ListView listView;
    ArrayList<Location> arrayOfLocations;
    LocationAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        // progress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressbar_loading);
        progress = new ProgressDialog(this);
        // Construct the data source
        arrayOfLocations = new ArrayList<Location>();
        // Create the adapter to convert the array to views
        adapter = new LocationAdapter(this, arrayOfLocations);
        adapter.add(new Location(null, "Title", null, null, null));
        adapter.add(new Location(null, "Title", null, null, null));
        adapter.add(new Location(null, "Title", null, null, null));
        adapter.add(new Location(null, "Title", null, null, null));
        adapter.add(new Location(null, "Title", null, null, null));
        adapter.add(new Location(null, "Title", null, null, null));
        adapter.add(new Location(null, "Title", null, null, null));
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        listView.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
            int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) { 
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Then, inside of onScroll, I put

```
if (listView.getLastVisiblePosition() == listView.getAdapter().getCount() - 1
     && listView.getChildAt(listView.getChildCount() - 1).getBottom() <= listView.getHeight()) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bottom!",
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Here, I am detecting the end of the current displayed entries and then display "Bottom!" but I get an error and my app crashed

Any ideas why? Thanks guys

**EDIT: **
Here is the logcat

```
06-04 14:47:00.670: W/dalvikvm(12719): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x419397c0)
06-04 14:47:00.670: E/AndroidRuntime(12719): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-04 14:47:00.670: E/AndroidRuntime(12719): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.test6/com.example.test6.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-04 14:47:00.670: E/AndroidRuntime(12719):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2339)
06-04 14:47:00.670: E/AndroidRuntime(12719):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2389)
06-04 14:47:00.670: E/AndroidRuntime(12719):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:153)
06-04 14:47:00.670: E/AndroidRuntime(12719):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1269)
06-04 14:47:00.670: E/AndroidRuntime(12719):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-04 14:47:00.670: E/AndroidRuntime(12719):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-04 14:47:00.670: E/AndroidRuntime(12719):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5289)
06-04 14:47:00.670: E/AndroidRuntime(12719):    at     java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-04 14:47:00.670: E/AndroidRuntime(12719):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
06-04 14:47:00.670: E/AndroidRuntime(12719):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739)
06-04 14:47:00.670: E/AndroidRuntime(12719):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
06-04 14:47:00.670: E/AndroidRuntime(12719):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-04 14:47:00.670: E/AndroidRuntime(12719): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-04 14:47:00.670: E/AndroidRuntime(12719):    at com.example.test6.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:62)
06-04 14:47:00.670: E/AndroidRuntime(12719):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
06-04 14:47:00.670: E/AndroidRuntime(12719):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
06-04 14:47:00.670: E/AndroidRuntime(12719):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2293)
```

Comment: You should add where exactly the `NullPointerException` occurs.

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin I have added the logcat

Comment: @oarfish I'm not exactly sure where it occurs...but it only happens when I add the second piece of code I listed in the original post

Comment: `at com.example.test6.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:62)` check line 62 of your code (we don't have the line numbers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm not exactly sure where it occurs...but it only happens when I add
>   the second piece of code I listed in the original post

I would add some null pointer checks to be safe. I suspect it's this part that is null:

```
listView.getChildAt(listView.getChildCount() - 1)
```

Try this:

```
if (listView.getLastVisiblePosition() == listView.getAdapter().getCount() - 1
     && listView.getChildAt(listView.getChildCount() - 1) != null
     && listView.getChildAt(listView.getChildCount() - 1).getBottom() <= listView.getHeight()) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bottom!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Just in case you want to take the extra leap of null pointer checks:

```
if (listView != null && listView.getAdapter() != null
     && listView.getChildAt(listView.getChildCount() - 1) != null
     && listView.getLastVisiblePosition() == listView.getAdapter().getCount() - 1
     && listView.getChildAt(listView.getChildCount() - 1).getBottom() <= listView.getHeight()) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bottom!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: This worked, thank you. If I may ask, WHY was this null? (If you know). Can't lie, got this "check for the bottom" code on the internet and I'm just wondering how it works and why it wasn't. Thanks again

Comment: @user1282637 Did you confirm which variable or was actually the `null` culprit?  Was it `listView.getChildAt(listView.getChildCount() - 1)`?

Comment: Only your second recommendation worked, so I'm assuming it was `&& listView.getLastVisiblePosition() == listView.getAdapter().getCount() - 1`

Comment: Does this say that the listener was trying to look for this before the adapter was filled?

Comment: Do prior `if` statements that check these values and print to your console or log that this is so-and-so value is `null`.  You can also use a debugger (which is the preferred way and less newbie way).